# Can I partially play back a Cassandra commit log?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

Let's say I have a Cassandra cluster that is backed up at 9:00.  Then at 9:30 I release some code that screws up all the data.  At 10:00 I notice the problem, but the damage is done.  Is there a way to play back the commit log up to 9:29?  I couldn't find any documentation about such a thing.  Would I just have to delete half the commit log file?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting half the commit log would do the trick. It's nicely formatted with timestamps so it should be trivial. Older versions of cassandra will automatically go through and replay the commitlog when you start it up.

Comment: Thanks, we'll give that a try.